# Как сверстать такую тень у блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На нижнем блоке будет еще параллакс, как сверстать такую двойную тень?

Comment: Тени сложной формы проще интегрировать в png, чем танцевать с бубном вокруг css

Answer (score 6):

```css
.box h3{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}
.effect
{
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*mONNI1lG9VuiqovpnYqicA.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}
.effect:before, .effect:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box effect">
</div>
```